# d3 x axis custom values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to force my x-axis to display ticks as below ?

```
3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,1,2
```

As you see from the jsfiddle example below, my line chart jumps back to the begining because my line values go as follow: 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,**24,1,2**...so basically when it comes to the highest value (24) it jumps back to the begining and it finishes the last 2 values there...we do not want that, we want the line to continue from 24 to 1 and 2..all in one line.

Please check my jsfiddle example below.

http://jsfiddle.net/a6psrawt/

Comment: Use [`axis.tickValues()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickValues), and you probably also want an ordinal scale instead of a linear one.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, can an ordinal scale be used with his data (decimal values)?

Comment: Yes you can use it with these values.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I can't figure out how to get the ordinal scale to play nice so here's my attempt with a fudged linear scale.

Changes in the code:

```
// max of the data, find this dynamically if needed
var maxValue = 24;
// which points are skipping up front
var wrapValue = 3;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
  // adjust domain
  .domain([wrapValue, maxValue + wrapValue])
  .range([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .ticks(maxValue)
  .tickFormat(function(d){
    if (d > maxValue){
      return d - maxValue; // fix axis value
    } else {
      return d;   
    }
})
.orient("bottom");

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d,i) {
    if (d[0] < wrapValue) {
        return x(d[0] + maxValue); // fix data value
    } else {
        return x(d[0]);
    }
  })
  .y(function(d, i) {return y(d[1]);});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6psrawt/1/).

Full code:

```js
var data =
[{"name":"Zu Hause","data":[[3,95.2],[3.15,95.2],[3.3,95.2],[3.45,95.3],[4,95.4],[4.15,95.2],[4.3,95],[4.45,94.7],[5,94.1],[5.15,93.7],[5.3,92.6],[5.45,91.9],[6,90.4],[6.15,89],[6.3,86.2],[6.45,83.7],[7,77.4],[7.15,74.5],[7.3,69.7],[7.45,66.6],[8,62.2],[8.15,60.2],[8.3,57.2],[8.45,55.6],[9,51.4],[9.15,50.5],[9.3,47.7],[9.45,47.1],[10,44.6],[10.15,44.3],[10.3,43.9],[10.45,44.1],[11,43.4],[11.15,44],[11.3,44.8],[11.45,45.7],[12,47.5],[12.15,49.4],[12.3,50.3],[12.45,50.3],[13,49.1],[13.15,49],[13.3,48.2],[13.45,47.9],[14,45.1],[14.15,45.4],[14.3,45.5],[14.45,45.9],[15,44.7],[15.15,45.4],[15.3,46.1],[15.45,46.7],[16,46.8],[16.15,48],[16.3,49.8],[16.45,51.4],[17,53.5],[17.15,55.8],[17.3,58.5],[17.45,60.2],[18,61.8],[18.15,64.6],[18.3,66.5],[18.45,68.1],[19,71.4],[19.15,72.2],[19.3,73.9],[19.45,74.7],[20,76],[20.15,77.8],[20.3,79.4],[20.45,80.8],[21,81.6],[21.15,82.7],[21.3,83.8],[21.45,85],[22,86.5],[22.15,87.6],[22.3,89.2],[22.45,90.2],[23,91.7],[23.15,92.3],[23.3,92.8],[23.45,93.4],[0,93.9],[0.15,94.3],[0.3,94.7],[0.45,95],[1,95.5],[1.15,95.6],[1.3,95.9],[1.45,96.1],[2,96.4],[2.15,96.6],[2.3,96.7],[2.45,96.9]]},{"name":"Unterwegs","data":[[3,0.7],[3.15,0.7],[3.3,0.9],[3.45,0.7],[4,0.6],[4.15,0.8],[4.3,0.9],[4.45,1.2],[5,1.2],[5.15,1.5],[5.3,2.1],[5.45,2.2],[6,3],[6.15,3.9],[6.3,5.8],[6.45,6.8],[7,8.9],[7.15,9.9],[7.3,10.6],[7.45,10.3],[8,9.3],[8.15,9.4],[8.3,10.1],[8.45,9.6],[9,11.1],[9.15,10.2],[9.3,11.4],[9.45,10.6],[10,12],[10.15,11.7],[10.3,11.5],[10.45,11.4],[11,13.5],[11.15,12.4],[11.3,11.8],[11.45,11.9],[12,12.4],[12.15,11.4],[12.3,11.3],[12.45,10.9],[13,12.8],[13.15,12.3],[13.3,13],[13.45,12.8],[14,15.2],[14.15,14.1],[14.3,13.6],[14.45,13.1],[15,17.3],[15.15,15.6],[15.3,14.8],[15.45,14.6],[16,17.2],[16.15,15.7],[16.3,16.4],[16.45,15.6],[17,17.2],[17.15,15.4],[17.3,14.3],[17.45,13.2],[18,15.3],[18.15,12.2],[18.3,11.6],[18.45,10.3],[19,10.3],[19.15,8.7],[19.3,7.2],[19.45,6.9],[20,6.6],[20.15,5.5],[20.3,5.1],[20.45,4.1],[21,4.5],[21.15,4],[21.3,3.8],[21.45,3.2],[22,3.7],[22.15,3.3],[22.3,2.9],[22.45,2.4],[23,2.3],[23.15,1.7],[23.3,1.5],[23.45,1.4],[0,1.3],[0.15,1],[0.3,1.2],[0.45,1],[1,0.9],[1.15,0.8],[1.3,0.8],[1.45,0.7],[2,0.7],[2.15,0.6],[2.3,0.6],[2.45,0.5]]}];  
  
  
var width = 560;
var height = 300;
var legendRectSize = 18;                                  
var legendSpacing = 4;                                    
var margin = {top: 50, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50}
var color = d3.scale.category20();  

//Create SVG container  
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top);

var maxValue = 24;
var wrapValue = 3;

var ticks = [0,25,50,75,100];
//X and Y Scales
var x = d3.scale.linear()
 .domain([wrapValue, maxValue + wrapValue])
    .range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear()
 .domain([0,100])
    .range([height, 0]);

//X and Y Axis init
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(x)
    .ticks(24)
 .tickFormat(function(d){
        if (d > maxValue){
            return d - maxValue;
        } else {
            return d;   
        }
    })
 .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(y)
 .tickValues(ticks)
 .tickFormat(function(d) { return d+'%'; })
 .orient("bottom"); 

var xAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
 .call(xAxis)
 .attr("class", "x axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+"," + (height + 20) + ")"); 

var yAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
 .call(yAxis)
 .attr("class", "y axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + 20 + ") rotate(90)")
 .selectAll("text")
 .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(-15,25) rotate(-90)"});

//Create a path container
var line = d3.svg.line()
 .x(function(d,i) {
        if (d[0] < wrapValue) {
            return x(d[0] + maxValue);
        } else {
            return x(d[0]);
        }
     })
 .y(function(d, i) {return y(d[1]);}); 
 
var g = svg.append("g")
 .attr('class','series-container')
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + 20 + ")");

var path = g.selectAll("path")
 .data(data).enter() 
 .append("g")     
 .attr('class','series') 
 .attr('id', function(d,i){ return 'pathid_'+d.name; })
 .append("path") 
 .attr("d", function(d,i){ return line(d.data); }) //Set d for every path
 .attr("fill", "none")
 .attr("stroke", function(d,i) { return color(i); })
 .attr("stroke-width", 3); 
 
var path_text = g.selectAll(".series")
    .append("text")
 .attr("transform", function(d,i) { return "translate("+(width+20)+", "+ y(d.data[d.data.length-1][1]) +")"; }) //+d[d.length-1].y+
 .attr("dy", ".35em")
 .style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i); })
 .text( function(d,i) {return d.name;} )
```

```css
body { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000; }
rect { stroke-width: 2; }
.chart-line { fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1px; }
.axis text { font-size: 12px; }
.axis .label { font-size: 22px; }
.axis path,
.axis line { fill: none; stroke: #000; shape-rendering: crispEdges; }
.tooltip { background: #000; color: #fff; padding: 3px; font-size: 11px; position: relative; }
.tooltip:before { content: ""; display: block; border-right: solid 3px #000; border-top: solid 3px transparent; border-bottom: solid 3px transparent; position: absolute; left: -3px; top: 50%; margin-top: -3px; }
.path-point circle,
.legend { cursor: pointer; font-size: 12px; }
.legend-container { display: none; }
.legend-title { margin: 0 0 4px }
.legend-container-jq { float: left; width: 100%; }
.legend-container-jq { list-style: none; margin: 0 0 10px 13px; padding: 0; }
.legend-container-jq li { float: left; width: 100%; margin: 3px 0; cursor: pointer; }
.legend-container-jq div { width: 15px; height: 15px; float: left; margin: 0 8px 0 0; }
.legend-container-jq span { float: left; margin: -2px 0 0 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```